# Android wifi call

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want make Phone calls from other devices using Wi-Fi connection in Android.

Please tell me is it possible ? Give me some sample code for that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And here's [the reason why people ask](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) :D

Answer (score 0):

There is p2p wifi connection in android from API Level 14.I think it can be used for your purpose. Look here for more details: [p2p](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html) , [wi-fi direct](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/wifip2p.html).